# clang static analyzer shows build failed

Tags: iphone

I used clang static analyzer but it produces a lot of html files and also it shows build failed.

Can anyone give details for how to use that html files.. and give tutorial link in detail?

Answer (score 0):

Here's [how to use clang on iPhone projects](http://www.rhonabwy.com/wp/2008/10/11/seattlebus-diary-using-clang-static-analyzer-with-an-iphone-project/).